# Get zero of String after decimal into floating point

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a string `string(5) "388.0"`. I simply want to get exactly `float number` with `one zero` or `two zero` or whatever numbers comes after decimal. How can I achieve it?

Simply (float)$val gives me only `float(388)` without `zero`.

Comment: You'll need to store the number of decimals before casting to float. Maybe a custom type (e.g. class) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$cost = [
301.215,
359.2487,
389.21,
32.0
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($cost); $i++) {
    $precision = @count(str_split(explode(".", $cost[$i])[1]));
    echo number_format($cost[$i], $precision)."\n";
}

//Output
301.215
359.2487
389.21
32.0
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

This will return the  number up to given precision

Comment: what if there are 5 digits after decimal ?

Comment: Check modified answer as per your comment

Comment: so, what about for a number not an array ? as in question, what would be the modified answer format?

Comment: Its a demonstration at least you should check as per your code it will ... If not an array don't use for loop

Comment: I'm not getting the logic of this. Applied to OP's case (ie with a `string` as an input), it will transform a `string` containing `n` decimals to a `string` containing `n` decimals. [Check here](https://eval.in/720739), it's the exact same string.

Comment: Php is not strict about data types it shows string but if you add something it will..  like `"12"+2 = 14`

Comment: I know, but you're missing my point. Check the [eval.in](https://eval.in/720739) and you'll see that the output string is exactly the same (value **and** type, using `===`) as the input one.

Comment: In That scenario float  print upto  least significant non 0  like `$a = 1.000300` and   `print $a` will result to `1.0003`  and you can't do anything about that

Comment: Hadn't thought of that scenario, good point, you should add this test case to your answer. It [works for an `int`](https://eval.in/720742), but [not for a `string`](https://eval.in/720743) though (which is the OP's input). Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function ?

```
<?php

$nb = '388.0';

var_dump(number_format((float)$nb, 0)); // string '388'
var_dump(number_format((float)$nb, 1)); // string '388.0'
var_dump(number_format((float)$nb, 2)); // string '388.00'
```

Of course, if you cast your string as a float, then it will by default be `(float)388` if the numbers after the decimal point are all `0`. I don't think there's a way around that, but `(float)388 === 388.0` is true.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php

```
var_dump(bcmul('388.0', '1', 2)); // string '388.0' (length=5)
var_dump(bcmul('388.00', '1', 2)); // string '388.00' (length=5)    
var_dump(bcmul('388.0021', '1', 4)); // string '388.0021' (length=5)
```